# MySQLdb configuration error while running Python manage.py makemigrations on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am setting up a web server for Python on Windows. While configuring `settings.py`, I changed the database to

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : '123456',
        'HOST' : 'localhost'
    }
}
```

I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` for verification of settings. It threw the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 25,in <module> import MySQLdb as Database ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:Traceback (most recent call last): File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line  utility.execute()File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute django.setup()ile "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate   app_config.import_models(all_models)File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module> from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 49,
in <module>class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 108, in __new__ new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 307, in add_to_class value.contribute_to_class(cls, name) File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length(
))
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 116, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 28,
in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Then I went to the Python 3 package index to install MySQLdb, but I did not find any supporting packages.

I have downloaded the  "mysqlclient-1.3.7-cp27-none-win32" from the Python 3 package index. I installed it with `pip install package_name`. I even tried installing the wheel package before installing it, but nothing is working. How do I connect MySQL on Windows?

This installation error is coming with Python 3.5.1.